# Add assets files to Laravel existing projects

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have existing laravel projects and I want to add assets files there.

This is code snippet for laravel blade file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<link href="{{elixir("css/app.css")}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

So I created custom.css file and try to edit gulpfile.js but not working.

How can I do this?

Also I can't find public folder as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Try checking the `config/filesystems.php` and look for the section `Filesystem Disks` and you might able to locate the public folder from that configuration. It has an array of `'disks' => 'local' => [ 'driver' = 'local', root => storage_path('app') ]...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could find public folder inside application folder.